# Maintain table width fixed

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with dynamic data.

Depending on data, it expands or collapses.

I don't want it. I want a fixed width that never expand or collapse.

How can I do that?

I've already tried `<table width="300px"></table>`,
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<table style="width:300px;table-layout:fixed"></table>
```

Comment: Is it larger or smaller then 300?  Do you have padding, spacing, margins, or borders on the table?

Answer (score 0):

You'd set the width of each column explicitly like so:

```
td.a {
   width:100px;
}
td.b { 
   width:200px;
}
...

<table>
<tr><td class='a'>A</td><td class='b'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td class='a'>A</td><td class='b'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td class='a'>A</td><td class='b'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td class='a'>A</td><td class='b'>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Either old ugly way

```
<table width="300"></table>
```

or the CSS way

```
<table style="width:300px"></table>
```

Of course, the best way is to use a separate stylesheet file, call it for example `style.css`:

```
table {
  width: 300px;
}
```

and your html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```